x64-linux becomes x64-1 when defining a macro?
I need to get a specific path of where something is installed, and then use that path to tell a program where to search at runtime.  This is working as expected on Windows, but on Linux (specifically Ubuntu running in WSL2), something odd is happening.
In my CMake I run the following:
find_package(PROJ CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_path(PROJ_DATA_DIR
    NAMES proj.db
    PATHS "${PROJ_DIR}"
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    REQUIRED
)
add_compile_definitions(MY_PROJ_DIR=${PROJ_DATA_DIR})
message(${PROJ_DATA_DIR})

This prints out:
/mnt/c/Users/cgnam/Source/Repos/vira/out/build/ubuntu/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/share/proj

which is the path I am expecting it to be.  In my c++ code however, when I inspect the value of the defined macro using:
#define STRINGIFY2(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY2(X)

...

std::cout << STRINGIFY(MY_PROJ_DIR);

it prints out:
/mnt/c/Users/cgnam/Source/Repos/vira/out/build/ubuntu/vcpkg_installed/x64-1/share/proj

This is nearly entirely correct, except the x64-linux has been replaced by x64-1.
This exact code works completely as expected when being built on Windows, so I am at a loss for why it is doing this when being built on Ubuntu.  Its especially odd to me that linux is being replaced by the integer 1, but this also feels intentional as if I am missing something.

Maybe you have #define linux 1 somewhere?

Try add_compile_definitions(MY_PROJ_DIR="${PROJ_DATA_DIR}")

#define linux 1 is non standard GCC pre-defined macro that they don't want to remove.

"This is nearly entirely correct, except the x64-linux has been replaced by x64-1." -- This suggests to me that one way to simplify your example code is std::cout << STRINGIFY(x64-linux);, which would let you drop the CMake part of your question. (If you're not too blinded by the intent, you might go as far as recognizing that - means subtraction, and try std::cout << STRINGIFY(linux);, but I'd say it's good enough to try to simplify away CMake.)

@JaMiT: Being used in a macro argument, the minus sign (-) isn't treated as a subtraction. It is passed directly to the preprocessor. Would preprocessor wrap that sign into a character literal or a string literal, the compiler won't perform subtraction either.

@Tsyvarev "Being used in a macro argument, the minus sign (-) isn't treated as a subtraction." -- So what? Unless you want to dispute that x64-linux can be parsed as x64, -, and linux, you're missing the point. I did not post an explanation of what is going on (that would be an answer, not a comment). I presented an avenue for experimentation that I think is within the OP's grasp, given the nature of the question. (If the OP takes another path to the same end, that's also fine.) You don't need fully accurate information as the basis of an experiment; that's why one experiments.

FWIW, so that I don't accidentally mislead someone, here is the full reasoning behind my proposed experiment, assuming one understands what's going on: One could recognize that - means subtraction in some contexts. This means the preprocessor has to treat - as its own token in some contexts. At this point, one could either try to determine if this is one of those contexts (recognizing that - has another meaning which would also require it to be its own token), or assume that this might be one of those contexts and proceed with the experiment. Experimenting is faster.

By default, for both GCC and Clang under Linux, linux is a predefined macro:
$ cpp -dM /dev/null | grep linux
#define __linux 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define linux 1
#define __linux__ 1

So, for example
#include <iostream>

#define MY_PROJ_DIR /mnt/c/Users/cgnam/Source/Repos/vira/out/build/ubuntu/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/share/proj

#define STRINGIFY2(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY2(X)

int main()
{
    std::cout << STRINGIFY(MY_PROJ_DIR);
}

prints
/mnt/c/Users/cgnam/Source/Repos/vira/out/build/ubuntu/vcpkg_installed/x64-1/share/proj

The "linux" part of the path is replaced with "1", as that is the value of the linux macro.
If you instead do add_compile_definitions(MY_PROJ_DIR="${PROJ_DATA_DIR}"), then your macro will be defined as if by
#define MY_PROJ_DIR "/mnt/c/Users/cgnam/Source/Repos/vira/out/build/ubuntu/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/share/proj"

As that is a string, the preprocessor won't perform macro replacement.
You also won't need the STRINGIFY macro and can just use MY_PROJ_DIR directly.

NOTE: some compiler flags will suppress the linux flag. According to gcc's documentation:

When the -ansi option, or any -std option that requests strict conformance, is given to the compiler, all the system-specific predefined macros outside the reserved namespace are suppressed. The parallel macros, inside the reserved namespace, remain defined.

For instance:
$ cpp -std=c99 -dM /dev/null | grep linux
#define __linux 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define __linux__ 1


On Linux, linux is a predefined macro This is not quite true. The presence of the macro depends on a compiler and compiler flags.

@3CxEZiVlQ Fixed
